# Server hosted on virtual machine with VPN can't be accessed on host machine using same VPN?

Tags: kali-linux, ip, vpn, openvpn, port

I am an absolute novice so there may be misunderstandings etc. any and all forms of help are very appreciated.

On a virtual machine (Virtual Box) using Kali Linux I am hosting [BeEF](https://beefproject.com) with OpenVPN configured using the vpn's private IP and I could on that machine access that private IP as a webpage.

Back on the host machine a Windows, I am also using OpenVPN and it has the same private IP (and Server Public IP) but if I try to use the private IP on a browser I just get a ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE (Opera GX).

On both systems for OpenVPN it is using the same profile by importing from the same .ovpn file so I assume the same settings for both.

Is there any way I can fix this? If I am doing something fundamentally wrong please let me know.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. What virtualization software do you use? How exactly did you configure the network of the virtual machine? Is your VPN configured to route between different VPN clients or only between a client and the network at the VPN server's side?

Comment: You can't use the same IP address for two different systems

Comment: Virtual machine is Virtual Box,  for VPN (OpenVPN) on both systems it's using the same .ovpn profile file so I think its the same settings. I'll edit in these to the actual question. Thanks